# How can I convert By class nls model list into data frame in R?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, nls

I have been trying to run a modified two pooled exponential decay model:

```
mass_loss ~ m1*exp(-k*cdi*t) + m2*exp(-k2*cdi*t)
```

over a dataframe (`decomp_Control`) with multiple sites and then extract the model coefficients into a data frame.

##### Setting up data

```
        decomp_control <- 
        structure(list(site_number = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), site_code = c("CCPp1a", "CCPp1b", "CCPp1c", "CCPp1d", 
"CCPp1e", "CCPp1f", "CCPp2a", "CCPp2b", "CCPp2c", "CCPp2d", "CCPp3a", 
"CCPp3b", "CCPp3c", "CCPp3d", "CCPp5a", "CCPp5b", "CCPp5c", "CCPp5d", 
"CMPp2a", "CMPp2b", "CMPp2c", "CMPp2d", "CMPp3a", "CMPp3b", "CMPp3c", 
"CMPp3d"), days_between = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), mass_remaining = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100), cdi_mean = c(0.636176396, 0.636176396, 
0.636176396, 0.636176396, 0.636176396, 0.636176396, 0.699725486, 
0.699725486, 0.699725486, 0.699725486, 0.664880103, 0.664880103, 
0.664880103, 0.664880103, 0.679079501, 0.679079501, 0.679079501, 
0.679079501, 0.681828353, 0.681828353, 0.681828353, 0.681828353, 
0.705206121, 0.705206121, 0.705206121, 0.705206121), m2 = c(43.65475, 
43.65475, 43.65475, 43.65475, 43.65475, 43.65475, 43.98935, 43.98935, 
43.98935, 43.98935, 44.08055, 44.08055, 44.08055, 44.08055, 44.3788, 
44.3788, 44.3788, 44.3788, 45.22985, 45.22985, 45.22985, 45.22985, 
45.41225, 45.41225, 45.41225, 45.41225), m1 = c(56.34525, 56.34525, 
56.34525, 56.34525, 56.34525, 56.34525, 56.01065, 56.01065, 56.01065, 
56.01065, 55.91945, 55.91945, 55.91945, 55.91945, 55.6212, 55.6212, 
55.6212, 55.6212, 54.77015, 54.77015, 54.77015, 54.77015, 54.58775, 
54.58775, 54.58775, 54.58775)), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")

     str(decomp_control)
    structure(list(site_number = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), site_code = c("CCPp1a", "CCPp1b", "CCPp1c", "CCPp1d", 
"CCPp1e", "CCPp1f", "CCPp2a", "CCPp2b", "CCPp2c", "CCPp2d", "CCPp3a", 
"CCPp3b", "CCPp3c", "CCPp3d", "CCPp5a", "CCPp5b", "CCPp5c", "CCPp5d", 
"CMPp2a", "CMPp2b", "CMPp2c", "CMPp2d", "CMPp3a", "CMPp3b", "CMPp3c", 
"CMPp3d"), days_between = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), mass_remaining = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100), cdi_mean = c(0.636176396, 0.636176396, 
0.636176396, 0.636176396, 0.636176396, 0.636176396, 0.699725486, 
0.699725486, 0.699725486, 0.699725486, 0.664880103, 0.664880103, 
0.664880103, 0.664880103, 0.679079501, 0.679079501, 0.679079501, 
0.679079501, 0.681828353, 0.681828353, 0.681828353, 0.681828353, 
0.705206121, 0.705206121, 0.705206121, 0.705206121), m2 = c(43.65475, 
43.65475, 43.65475, 43.65475, 43.65475, 43.65475, 43.98935, 43.98935, 
43.98935, 43.98935, 44.08055, 44.08055, 44.08055, 44.08055, 44.3788, 
44.3788, 44.3788, 44.3788, 45.22985, 45.22985, 45.22985, 45.22985, 
45.41225, 45.41225, 45.41225, 45.41225), m1 = c(56.34525, 56.34525, 
56.34525, 56.34525, 56.34525, 56.34525, 56.01065, 56.01065, 56.01065, 
56.01065, 55.91945, 55.91945, 55.91945, 55.91945, 55.6212, 55.6212, 
55.6212, 55.6212, 54.77015, 54.77015, 54.77015, 54.77015, 54.58775, 
54.58775, 54.58775, 54.58775)), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")
```

My nls model is as follows:

```
two_pool <- function(m1,k1,cdi,t,m2,k2){(m1*exp(-k1*cdi*t)+
                                           m2*exp(-k2*cdi*t))
}

nls(mass_remaining ~ two_pool(m1,k1,cdi_mean,days_between,
                                      m2,k2),
            start = list(k1 = 0.0121, k2 = 0.000000000001696), data = decomp_Control)
```

I have tried running the nls model across categories of site_code and have only found one way that works, which is probably not the best so any advice is welcome.

```
models <- by(decomp_Control, decomp_Control$site_code, function(x) {
  fm <- nls(mass_remaining ~ two_pool(m1,k1,cdi_mean,days_between,
                                      m2,k2),
            start = list(k1 = 0.0121, k2 = 0.000000000001696), data = decomp_Control)
  fm
})
```

I have tried to turn this model into a dataframe so I can easily extract the model coefficients which have all failed.  Below are my attempts with the respective errors:

```
mod_list <- list(models)

output_list <- mod_list %>% 
  map(unlist) %>% 
  do.call(cbind.data.frame, .)
```

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
cannot coerce class ‘"nls"’ to a data.frame

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(mod_list, function(x) as.data.frame.list(unlist(x))))
```

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
cannot coerce class ‘"nls"’ to a data.frame

I have tried a few other techniques which created data frames but saved the coefficients as the string "numeric".

Any help with either looping the nls model more efficiently or extracting the model coefficients is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (1) data.table objects cannot be used with `dput` because they contain an internal pointer.  Convert to data.frame first before using `dput`. (2) The code shown in the question results in a singular gradient matrix.  Please fix so others can run it.

Comment: @G.Gothendieck , I have rectified the dput error and checked that the code runs.  I do not get singular fit when running so hopefully it's the same for you.

Comment: You are likely not using the data your posted but some other version since the name of the data is not even the same in the posted data and the code.  Also the str output is clearly not the input shown above it since it has an internal pointer whereas the data above it does not.  Please start a fresh session and then try copying and pasting the code and data from the question into it.

Comment: @G.Gothendieck I forgot to put the new structure after editing the dput data frame.  Your comment has raised a further issue, if I run the nls model on a singular site I get a singular fit but it works using the models object.  I will investigate this and post an update.